# How to receive attachments from a user with Bot Framework in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, skype

I am developing a bot in C# with Bot Framework and I would like to obtain the attachments sent by the users.

They seem to be in a location similar to this one:

```
ContentType: audio
ContentURL: https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/attachments/0-weu-d9-734cab9e78c28a1619a39ce8c69342d1/views/original
Name: 2-audioMessage.m4a
```

When I do a get request it shows me the following:

```
{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

How can I get the attachments? (in my case they are voice notes in Skype).

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be closely related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794242/get-skype-voice-notes-in-a-bot).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to receive an image send by users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674291/how-to-receive-an-image-send-by-users)

Answer (score 0):

you get the attachments from activity instance in turnContext object, you can add your custom code to save it in specific location like azure storage or sharepoint library